# _T("") macro for non-MFC, Win32 projects

Tags: winapi, mfc, tchar

I'm creating a Win32 project, and I'm trying to use `TCHAR` everywhere. But since it's a non-MFC project, I don't have `_T` defined.

How do I get it in my project?

Comment: The creation of `_T` was a solution to a temporary problem - how to handle the transition of Windows programs from MBCS to Unicode. That problem shouldn't exist anymore except for legacy code, and there's typically no reason not to use `L""` for your strings if you need wide characters.

Comment: I believe there is - copying and pasting code from ASCII project to Unicode project and vice-versa. It's source compatibility.

Comment: But that's my point - ASCII projects shouldn't exist anymore, at least as Windows programs. Maybe for console programs they're still OK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, found out how to do it. I just need to add

```
#include <tchar.h>
```

to `stdafx.h`, and it doesn't carry any MFC dependencies. It's just not included by default in non-MFC projects.